# Spltting a string based on a word

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am currently trying to split a string based on a particular word. 
An example of what I am trying to achieve is

```
string =" Total number of boys is 2020 , Total number of states could be 19? Total number of votes is 400"
```

I want the string to be split whenever it comes across the word Total.
 I want the result of the split to be of the following pattern

```
results=['Total number of boys is 2020 ,' , 'Total number of states could be 19? ', 'Total number of votes is 400']
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will find sentences starting with 'Total' and ending with punctuation characters `.`, `,` or `?`. You have not mentioned the requirement to limit the extracted strings with punctuation marks, but I suspect you will find it handy.

```
>>> [m[0] + m[2] for m in re.findall('(Total(.*?))([,?.]|$)', string)]
['Total number of boys is 2020 ,', 'Total number of states could be 19?', 'Total number of votes is 400']
```

Comment: From what I can see he wants to keep the punctuation marks in the sub-strings

Comment: OK, I left only the version which keeps punctuation marks.

Answer (score 1):

```
def word_splitter(string, word):
    my_list = []
    for phrase in string.split(word):
        if len(phrase.strip()) > 0:
            my_list.append('%s%s' % (word, phrase))
    return my_list
```

So

```
string =" Total number of boys is 2020 , Total number of states could be 19? Total number of votes is 400"
word_splitter(string, 'Total ')
```

returns

```
['Total number of boys is 2020 , ', 'Total number of states could be 19? ', 'Total number of votes is 400']
```

Comment: I'd use 'Total ' in both so you ensure is the whole word and your append looks nicer. Matter of taste though...

Comment: Wrote a function. So much better, don't you think? :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
re.findall('(?:Total|^).*?(?=(?:Total)|$)', string)
```

result:

```
[' ', 'Total number of boys is 2020 , ', 'Total number of states could be 19? ', 'Total number of votes is 400']
```

Answer (score 0):

Below can split the line as required.
First we split the string "string" then add it to "delimiter"

```
['Total' + item for index, item in enumerate(string.split('Total')) if index!=0 and item]
```

result:

```
['Total number of boys is 2020 , ', 'Total number of states could be 19? ', 'Total number of votes is 400']
```